# Creating secondary legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a barplot overlaid with points to illustrate percent diesel emissions (points) and attributable percent decline per sector (bars). I want to create a secondary legend so I have two different ones (one for color fill in the barplot and the other for the shape). I cannot figure out the best way to create two separate legends instead of having one combined legend. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
c <- ggplot(diesel_sectorC, 
            aes(factor(Year), Percent, fill=Sector)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "dodge") +
  xlab("Time Interval") + 
  ylab("Percent (%) of Attributable Decline") + 
  ggtitle("CA Percent Attributable Emissions") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Total, grou = Sector), 
             stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
             size = 3, color = "black", shape = 3) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold.italic"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="#993333", size=14, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="#993333", size=14, face="bold")) + 
  scale_fill_manual("Sector", 
                    values = c("HDDV" = "slateblue1", "Construction" = "steelblue1", 
                               "LDDV" = "paleturquoise3", "Marine" = "thistle")) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Attributable Decline Sectors"))
```

Comment: Could you share some sample data, or perhaps recreate a similar plot on built-in data? I can't run your plot without data, but it looks like you don't map anything to `shape`, so I'm not sure what combined legend you are getting -- it seems like you should only have a single `fill` legend. I also don't understand what you want the separate `shape` legend to say, since you only use one shape.

Comment: Perhaps if you just mapped shape to something? `aes(shape = "shape legend value")` in your `geom_point` layer? Perhaps combined with  `+ scale_shape_manual(values = 3, name = "My shape legend title")`